# Google Chrome extension that can bypass ads in Hulu?

Tags: chrome, ad-blocker

I don't actually think there is one but is there an extension for Google Chrome that can bypass these ads?

The reason I want to bypass them is because they are overly long and come back every ten minutes. You may tell me to go buy Hulu Plus, but even that still has ads in it.

Is there a Google Chrome extension that can help me remove them?

Oh yeah and some nice to haves are it is undetectable!

Comment: Some sites tend to work well with [Adblock Pro](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-pro/ocifcklkibdehekfnmflempfgjhbedch), but I haven't tried it with Hulu 
(since i'm in Canada). Maybe give that a try?